# Why if $P(x) = (x-a)Q(x)$ where $Q(x)$ is linear, $P(x)$ must have $2$ roots over prime modulus?

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic, roots, factoring

I am wondering how to formalize the logic behind the following answer:

> 4. Any polynomial of degree exactly 2 over arithmetic modulo a prime $p>2$ has either 0 roots or 2 roots. **Answer**: True. Any linear polynomial has one root as one can set it to zero and solve. If there is 1 root, then factoring gives another.

I am trying to formally justify why if there is 1 root, then factoring yields another. I know that if polynomial of degree $d$ $P(x)$ has a root $a$, then it can be written as $(x-a)Q(x)$ for some degree $d-1$ polynomial $Q(x)$. We could then set $Q(x) \equiv 0 \pmod p$ and solve for $x$; however, **how do we formally show that there is a solution and that the solution is different than $a$?**

Comment: If $\,Q\,$is linear then $\,Q \equiv ax+b\,$ with $\,a\not\equiv 0\,$ so $\,x \equiv -b/a\,$ is a second root (which may be $\equiv a),\,$ i.e. $P$ has $2$ roots including *multiplicity* in the count). $\ \ $

Comment: Generally if $\,P = (x-r_1)^{\large n_1}\cdots (x-r_k)^{\large n_k} Q$ where $\,Q\,$ has no roots then the number of roots of $P$ (counting *multiplicity*) is $\,n_1 + \cdots + n_k\,$ whereas the number of *distinct* roots is $\,k.\ \ $

Comment: Based on reading many of your past questions, it seems likely that you would understand these topics much more deeply if you studied a bit of ring theory.